# Logging different levels to different logs in cloud watch from an aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been trying to find a solution for a problem we have, in our application we have different types of logs. We want to log changes to (for example) the database in a different way than simple errors or code execution information.

Currently we're using the default asp.net core logging and i'm hoping we can stay with this. At the moment everything gets written to the same log in AWS cloudwatch.

Is there a way to seperate the logs?

I know with Serilog you can output different log levels to different files as explained in this answer: [ASP.NET Core logging in 2 different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261633/asp-net-core-logging-in-2-different-files)

I'm looking for something similar but for cloudwatch.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean with different types of logs and how you want to distinguish these differences?

Comment: Sorry, didn´t get a notification of your edit.. If I got you right, you can do the exact same thing, but with the sink you´re using..